# as hard as you can vs as hard as you could

Tags: difference

(1) You are not working as hard as you **can** to learn how to ski.

I think there is nothing with (1). I will change the modal verb, can, to its past tense.

(2) You are not working as hard as you **could** to learn how to ski.

Besides the tense difference, how does the past tense, could, change the meaning of the first sentence in which "can" is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Could' exists both as a modal (auxiliary) verb and as the past tense of the modal verb 'can'.

This (with some reformating for clarity) is from the [M-WD definition of 'could'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/could).

**could** auxiliary verb

1. past tense of CAN

-- used in auxiliary function in the past
e.g. *We found we could go.*

-- used in the past conditional
e.g. *We said we would go if we could.*

2. an alternative to CAN, suggesting less force or certainty or as a polite form in the present
   e.g. *If you could come, we would be pleased.*

In your example, 'could' is being used meaning #2, as a less forceful alternative to 'can'.

Comment: Thanks, Ross. Your explanation is very clear and understandable.